# Twitter4j - cannot resolve method - setUsessl(boolean)

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter4j

I'm using twitter4j 4.0.3 core

I have this code:

```
public final class TwitterUtil {

private RequestToken requestToken = null;
private TwitterFactory twitterFactory = null;
private Twitter twitter;

private TwitterUtil() 
{

    ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(ConstantValues.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(ConstantValues.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    configurationBuilder.setUseSSL(true);

    Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
    twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
    twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();

    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(ConstantValues.PREFERENCE_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN,ConstantValues.PREFERENCE_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
}

public TwitterFactory getTwitterFactory()
{
    return twitterFactory;
}

public void setTwitterFactory(AccessToken accessToken)
{
    twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance(accessToken);
}

public Twitter getTwitter()
{
    return twitter;
}
public RequestToken getRequestToken() {
    if (requestToken == null) {
        try {
            requestToken = twitterFactory.getInstance().getOAuthRequestToken(ConstantValues.TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
    return requestToken;
}

static TwitterUtil instance = new TwitterUtil();

public static TwitterUtil getInstance() {
    return instance;
}


public void reset() {
    instance = new TwitterUtil();
}
}
```

But it always throws this error on `setUseSSL`:

```
cannot resolve method - setUsessl(boolean)
```

What it may be? Maybe a version issue?

Also, on my module build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j:4.0.3'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-appengine:4.0.3'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.3'
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar')
}
```

I placed a file unto libs folder, trying to add it from here, no matter if I delete the other versions, the jar seems not to be working, or added to the project, also I can't see my project root 'libs' folder from IDE.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following configuration:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setOAuthAuthenticationURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
cb.setOAuthAuthorizationURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
        cb.setOAuthRequestTokenURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
cb.setRestBaseURL("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/");
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
```

You should not set **cb.setUseSSL(true);**

I hope this helps.

Zoran

Comment: Hi, @zoran Thank you, should I replace consumerKey and consumerSecret with the actual data?

Comment: Yes. You should register your application to use Twitter API and use those consumer key and consumer secret.

Comment: Yes, but it says it cannot resolve symbol, I mean I should then use a declaration called consumerKey and consumerSecret right?

Comment: On that declaration then use the keys I guess

Comment: Yes. Before this you should initialize these variables and assign real values, e.g. String consumerKey="yourkey"; String consumerSecret="yoursecret"; where "yourkey" and "yoursecret" are some values you got on https://apps.twitter.com/ when you registered your application.